# "Workspace in use" error when trying to open multiple .php files

Tags: aptana, workspace

I've been using Aptana as my IDE for the past year.  I recently bought a new computer and installed Aptana fresh, but have run into a problem I've never seen before with Aptana.  Generally with Aptana set as my default editor I can click a .php file, it will load into the editor, and if I subsequently click another .php file it will load in a new tab.

Now when I click a second .php file another instance of Aptana launches and I get the error that the Workspace is in use.  Any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the program - [Bug Discussion](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2084-opening-new-file-opens-new-aptana). Apparently there is a fix but to get to it you have to register at Aptana to view the workaround. Too many hoops and bugs for me so am going to uninstall Aptana and use Netbeans from now on.